# GET WSDL file using Savon SOAP GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

I am trying to establish a connection using the ruby gems Savon and execute SOAP requests and responses. The thing is that I am getting the file each time by doing this:

```
client = Savon.client("http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL")
```

Now in the documentation of Savon it says this:

"You can instantiate a client with or without a (local or remote) WSDL document. Using a WSDL is a little easier because Savon can parse the document for the target namespace, endpoint, available SOAP actions etc. But the (remote) WSDL has to be downloaded and parsed once for every client which comes with a performance penalty."

So my question is, can I get the WSDL file by just using the Savon Library? Or do I need to ask for it from the third party application?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the service, and whether or not they offer the .WSDL from their service URL. Best bet for availability may be to store the WSDL locally, but at that point you commit yourself to tracking their updates